# Not able to read attachment from email using javamail api

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

Not able to read attachment from email using javamail 1.4 api.
There have multiple attachment into mail file but when I am reading mail file it's **showing Content type :: text/plain**.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.host", "smtp.abcd.com");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    InputStream source = new FileInputStream(emlFile);
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession, source);


    //System.out.println("Subject : " + message.getSubject());
    //System.out.println("From : " + message.getFrom()[0]);
    //System.out.println("--------------");
 // suppose 'message' is an object of type Message
    String contentType = message.getContentType();
    System.out.println(message.getDisposition());
    System.out.println("File name : "+message.getFileName());
    System.out.println("Content type :: "+contentType);
    if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
        System.out.println("Content type multipart :: "+contentType);
    }

    String mailBody= "";
    Object content = message.getContent();
    //message.get
   // check for string  
    if (content instanceof Multipart) {
        // then check for multipart
        Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content; 
        procesMultiPart(multiPart);
        }else if (content instanceof String) { 
            mailBody =(String) message.getContent();
        }
```

Output: 
null
File name : null
Content type :: text/plain
Please suggest me how to read attached mail file from email file

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach) will help, as will the [msgshow.java sample program](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples).

Comment: I gone through but didn't find any solution from bellow given links  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach   thanks for your efforts, @BillShannon

Comment: Did you look at the same program?  It includes code to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes boss, it's not enough for that I am only getting content-type - text/plain, I am not getting multipart. :(

Comment: Then your message has no attachment, or it's not in the standard MIME format.  If you have an example of a message that you think contains an attachment but is only showing up with a content type of text/plain, post it here.